# Descarga de archivos de mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de descargar un archivo que tengo almacenado en la base de datos, pero al momento de descargarlo no se abre, dice que el formato no es compatible, este es el código de descarga:

```
<?php  

include '../modelo/ConMod.php';

if (isset($_GET['id_tarea']))
    {
         
         
      
      $id = $_GET['id_tarea'];
      

     $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea ='$id'"); 
      

$data=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

echo $data["archivo"];

       
      } 
?>
```

esta es la tabla de donde se descarga el archivo

```
 
          <tbody id="myTable">

            <?php 
            $sql="SELECT id_tarea, titulo, contenido, archivo from tareas
                where id_tarea = '$id_mod'";

            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);

            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           ?> 
 
            <div class="user-panel20">
            </div>
            <td><h3><?php echo strtoupper($mostrar ['titulo']) ?></h3> <br>
                <?php echo $mostrar ['contenido'] ?></td>

      </tbody>

              </table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><a title="Descargar Archivo" a href="descargar_files.php?id_tarea=<?php echo $mostrar ['archivo']; ?>" download="<?php echo $mostrar ['archivo']; ?>" style="color: blue; font-size:18px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mostrar ['archivo'] ?></td>
                  </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o es alguna configuración, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por qué envías como `id_tarea=<?php echo $mostrar ['archivo'];` el archivo? No deberías enviar el id `$mostrar['id_tarea']`?

Comment: Para depurar pon un `var_dump($data);` antes del `header` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: @Bicho esa parte del codigo es solo para mostrar en pantalla el nombre del archivo, si lo cambiara por id_tarea me mostraria el id de la tarea en pantalla.

Comment: Estás enviando esto `"descargar_files.php?id_tarea=<?php echo $mostrar ['archivo']; ?>"` y el select que haces supuestamente lo comparas con `id_tarea`. Qué valor te imprime `$_GET['id_tarea'];`?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo puse pero no muestra nada

Comment: Debe mostrar por lo menos `NULL` o algo. Si no muestra nada, ni siquiera estás llegando a ese archivo.

Comment: Está mal formulada esta pregunta.